# have(string) want() Cannot understand

Tags: go

I've completed the Go course but I cannot think as to why this function isn't working and I am just guessing at this point

Error message:
./form.go:34:2: too many arguments to return
have (string)
want ()

```
func main() {
    name()
}
 
func name() {
    nameapi, err := http.Get("https://randomuser.me/api/")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    nameapiData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(nameapi.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(nameapiData)) // If not in string, byte form
    var responseObject Response
    json.Unmarshal(nameapiData, &responseObject)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println()
 
    fmt.Println(responseObject.Results[0].Name.First)
    //flname := responseObject.Results[0].Name.First + " " + response.Object.Results[0].Name.Last
    returnvalue := responseObject.Results[0].Name.First
    return returnvalue
}

type Response struct {
    Results []struct {
        Gender string `json:"gender"`
        Name   struct {
            Title string `json:"title"`
            First string `json:"first"`
            Last  string `json:"last"`
        } `json:"name"`
    }
}
```

Edited to add struct.

Answer (score 6):

Your function is declared as:

```
func name()
```

This means that it takes no arguments and returns nothing.

However, you are attempting to return `returnvalue` which is probably a string given the error.

Either use a naked return or specify that the function must return a string:

```
func name() string
```

I recommend you take the [tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/), this is covered fairly early on.

Comment: I did it a while ago, I'll do it again as I'm clearly rusty